# C# Cannot access a disposed object when adding rows asynchronously to a winform datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task, objectdisposedexception

I am loading docs in a datagridview from a parallel thread using the code below:
inside a block `Task.Run(() => {});`

When I close the form I get ObjectDisposedException `Cannot access a disposed object.` Looks like the `if (IsDisposed || Disposing)` fails and the code attempts to add a row and in the meantime Disposing has became true.

I could catch this exception but it is dirty.

Adding a flag enabled when closing the form to check if the form has been closed does not work as well. It seems to behave the same way as `this.Disposing`

Adding a `Thread.Sleep(5);` before `if (this.IsDisposed || this.Disposing)` seems enough to avoid the exception to be raised though I am not sure if it could be raised if unlucky enough.

What would probably be the best practice to avoid this issue ?

```
  foreach (var doc in docList)
  {
     if (this.InvokeRequired)
     {
         if (IsDisposed || Disposing || dgv.IsDisposed || dgv.isposing) return;
         this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { dgv.Rows.Add(doc.Name); }));
     }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you just want to hide form?

Comment: You aren't addding rows asynchronously to the gridview. You *can't* add rows asynchronously to the gridview or any other UI element. `Invoke` means "run on the UI thread". This code simply wastes a background thread, to add rows in the slowest way possible on the UI thread, forcing a redraw each time a row is added.

Comment: You should remove *all* of this code and simply bind the gridview to the collection or datatable that contains the data. How much data is there anyway? Humans can't see 100s of rows at once, nor can you display them. If you have a lot of data use paging and virtualized scrolling to load only what's needed

Comment: Furthermore, don't use `async void` except in event handlers. The signature for asynchronous methods that don't return results is `async Task`. You can't await or stop or handle anything that runs with `async void`

Comment: What is your *actual* problem? Why are you trying to "load a grid asynchronously"? Did you encounter a performance problem? Are you adding messages as soon as they arrive? Are you trying to display too many things at once? Something else? Whatever it is, there are techniques to deal with it since .NET 1.0 came out 15 years ago. None involves `async`

Comment: For example, all you need to load the data is to assign the list to the [DataSource property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control), eg `dgv.DataSource = docList`. No need for loops or `Rows.Add`

Comment: I stopped using datasource long ago because of poor maintainability. I am letting a parallel thread to add the row to avoid freezing the UI. Connection is not so fast because it is requesting objects having System.Data.Linq.Binary field.

Comment: Sorry about the async I removed this from the question it's actually not being used, rows are indeed added from a parallel thread using Task.Run()

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you want to do with form after closing. If it's okay to just hide it use this:

```
private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to use unnecessary resources. Why not closing the form ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding conditions inside Invoke:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
    {
        foreach (var doc in docList)
        {
            if (IsDisposed || Disposing || dgv.IsDisposed || dgv.isposing)  return;
            dgv.Rows.Add(doc.Name); 
        }));
    }
}
```